# How to capture global short key on Mac to create short key frequency

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

How to capture global short key on Mac to create short key frequency in Xcode or any other tools.

I want to analyze which short key are used the most on a daily basis.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting use case. Have you already done some research on what's available? E.g. have you searched the web for `analyze "keyboard usage" mac` or something similar? What did you find? If you found something, why did it not solve your problem?
Please include your prior research in the question such that others can provide you with more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

As I research and try.

These are repo that have native swift code to solve my problem

https://github.com/topics/keystrokes

This repo solves my problem